# Minimum rule to create a square button with a letter exactly at the center

Tags: css

When tying to create a button consisting a single letter/glyph how to align that vertically so the letter place exactly at the center of its parent.

Link to [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/dpee96L4/)

```css
div {
  width: 2em;
  height: 2em;
  background: gray;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 2em;
}
```

```html
<div>⬛</div>or
<div>@</div>or
<div>g</div>
```

Comment: could you show a jsfiddle?

Answer (score 1):

There is no *one-rule* that can do this.

Some character glyphs, such at those with descenders like `y` and `g` simply are **not centered** in their 'bounding box'.

Equally, even if you came up with a consistent method for centering on one typeface, this would not translate to a second/alternate typeface / font even at the same font-size.

```css
.wrap div {
  width: 1.2em;
  height: 1.2em;
  line-height: 1.2em;
  border: solid thin;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 72px;
}
.wrap {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin-right: 1em;
}
.times {
  font-family: "Verdana";
}
.calibri {
  font-family: "calibri";
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap times">
  <div>⬛</div>or
  <div>@</div>or
  <div>g</div>or
  <div>~</div>
</div>

<div class="wrap calibri">
  <div>⬛</div>or
  <div>@</div>or
  <div>g</div>or
  <div>~</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You could try this:

```
<div>g</div>

div{
width: 1em;
height: 1em;
text-align: center;
background: gray;
padding: 5px 10px 10px 10px;}
```

Adjust padding on top or bottom. https://jsfiddle.net/5vwh46f8/

Answer (score -1):

Add line-height equal to the height.

```
div {
  width: 1.2em;
  height: 1.2em;
  border: solid thin;
  text-align: center;

  line-height: 1.2em;
}
```

That way, the square is exactly at the center. Other letters might be slightly out of center if the glyph is tall or uppercase or when it is a letter with descent, like `y` to bottom, but it will look natural IMO.